# the bar of crystal report does not display in IE 11

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

when i Generate the Crystal report in the usual manner. The tool bar at the top of the generated report that gives the options to Export, Print, navigate page-to-page within the report, increase/decrease view size of the report, and search the report this bar was shown in FireFox and GoogleChrome but it does not shown in IE 11

Answer (score 0):

That's unusual.

Can you check if the site is in displaying in compatibility mode.
If the domain, or intranet sites are displayed in compatibility mode the output is sometimes different. Toggle the compatibility settings.

[image]
[image]

Failing that, verify that the DisplayToolBar property is set to true.

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" DisplayToolbar="True"
```